# Algorithm for factoring a 30 decimal digit number

Tags: rsa, factoring

My professor has given me an RSA factoring problem as an assignment. The given modulus is 30 decimal digits long. I have been searching a lot about factoring algorithms. But it has been quite a headache to choose one for my given requirements. Which algorithms give the best performance for 30 decimal digit numbers?

Note: So far I have read about Brute force approach and Quadratic Sieve. The latter is complex and the former time consuming.

Comment: Factoring a 30 digits number is an easy task. As an example, you can type Factorization(10263280077814176196883978050069); at http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/ and see the result. You can change my number and see the decumentation for details of factorization methods.

Comment: @MeysamGhahramani Thank you for answering it. However in a night's search I have found pollard-rho to be the one that suits my requirement. nevertheless, once again thank you.

Comment: Use Linux factor command? Also Wolfram alpha can do that for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which algorithms give the best performance for 30 decimal digit numbers?

30 decimal digits is 100 binary digits.

- Trial division will require around $2^{50}$ divisions.
- [Pollard-Rho-Factoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm) will require around $2^{25}$ checks - this may be a good pick for you if you want to implement it yourself quickly and don't mind having to wait a bit on an optimized execution result.
- Most decent quadratic sieve implementations will do this number within seconds.
- Most [ECM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra_elliptic-curve_factorization) implementations will do that too. If you need something more optimized than Pollard-Rho, using ECM is probably a good pick. Refer to [this database](https://hyperelliptic.org/EFD/) for optimal curve representation choices and [the Handbook of Applied Cryptography](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/) (Ch14, [PDF](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap14.pdf)) for fast scalar multiplication strategies.